# How do you render @ContentChildren bodies in Angular6

Tags: angular

I'm making a pretty simple tab view (want something custom as I will be modifying this heavily later), but stuck with one basic step of getting the child tab to render.

My template for the tab-view (container for the tabs) is:

```
  <div class="card info-panel">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; index as i; first as isFirst" class="nav-item">
          <a [ngClass]="{'nav-link': true, 'active':isFirst}" id="tab-{{i}}" href="#">{{tab.label | translate}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs; index as i; first as isFirst" [ngClass]="{'tab-pane': true, 'active': isFirst}" id="tab-{{i}}" role="tabpanel">
          tab content goes here.. {{tab}} 
          <!-- this is where im trying to get the tab to render, using the object instance "tab" is a <app-tab> component -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the tab temlate is simply:

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

how im using the tabs is:

```
<app-tab-view title="My Tabs">
    <app-tab label="General">this is the content for the general tab </app-tab>
    <app-tab label="Other">this is the content for the other tab </app-tab>
</app-tab-view>
```

clearly {{tab}} isnt the correct way to render the child tab, but how do i render these ?  I wish to wrap each child tab hence me not just using "" in the tab-view template,

Comment: Given that your tab template is a component, you need to refer to it using its selector. Ex: `<mytab attr1="ho">Foo Bar content.</mytab>`. You can use a repeater on it as well.

Comment: how would I do that in this example?   I'm iterating the list of tabs and the reference to the tab I want to render is "tab".  At this point its an object.   putting a new selector there would create a new instance wouldnt it?  It wouldn't magically know to use the value from "tab"